# Can I use .otf or .ttf extension fonts for @font-face property in CSS?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts, truetype

```css
@font-face{
  font-family: myriad;
  src: url(myriadpro.ttf);
  }
```

Can anyone tell me which extensions are valid for its usage like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use all font file format like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```